# Extra Space from the top of the screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to set a background image for my screens using SwiftUI.
I noticed that there is some kind of inset from the top of the screen around 10px, and am not sure what is that? and how to start the image from the very top.

Here is my code:

```
struct AppBackGround: ViewModifier {
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
             ZStack {
                Image("background")
                    .resizable()

                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,
                           height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height, alignment: .top)

//                    .clipped()

                    .border(Color.red, width: 1)
                    .Print(UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
                
                content
         }

             .background(Color.red)
    }
}

extension View {
    func withAppBackground() -> some View {
        self.modifier(AppBackGround())
    }
}

struct AppBackGround_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            ZStack {
                Text("iphone 8 plus")
            }
            .withAppBackground()
            .colorScheme(.light).previewDevice("iPhone 8 Plus")
            
            ZStack {
                Text("iphone 11")
            }
            .withAppBackground()
            .colorScheme(.light).previewDevice("iPhone 11")
        }
    }
}
```

In the picture below you can see that there is a red border that surrounds the exact frame of the image. and you can notice that there is a space between the top of the image and the top of the screen.
[image: 8+]

Here is the original image as well, if you want to try it out.

[image: original]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say exactly what that little space is, but to fix it you can move the `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` from the `Image` to the `ZStack` which encloses the entire `View`:

```
struct AppBackGround: ViewModifier {
    

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
             ZStack {
                Image("background")
                    .resizable()

                    // .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)  // remove this

                    .scaledToFill()
                    .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,
                           height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height, alignment: .top)

//                    .clipped()

                    .border(Color.red, width: 1)
                    .Print(UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
                
                content
         }

             .background(Color.red)
             .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)   // add this
    }
}
```

---

`AppBackGround` can be further simplified by making the `Image` an `overlay` of the background `Color.red`.  This allows for the removal of the `frame` since the `Color.red` will fill the screen because of the `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)`.

```
struct AppBackGround: ViewModifier {
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
         ZStack {
            Color.red
                .overlay(
                    Image("background")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                )
                .border(Color.red, width: 1)
            
            content
         }
         .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

Comment: That actually worked!   thank you, but wondering why do we have to use an overlay here why not the image directly.

Comment: If you use the image directly, it will decide how big the view is.  In the case of a wide image, you would end up with a view that is much wider than the screen.  By letting the `Color.red` (or `Rectangle()`) establish the view size, the `.overlay()` will not change it.  The image will then be scaled to fill the bounds established by the parent view.  This allows the `content` then to be centered on a view that is the size of the phone screen.

Comment: The alternative is to do what you originally did and give the image an explicit frame.  The overlay looks neater to me, but the frame also works well.  You could use a `GeometryReader` to establish the size of the frame without having to hard code it to `UIScreen.main.bounds` which isn't very SwiftUI like.

Comment: I see, your solution works better, the frame whether using `GeometryReader` or `UIScreen` did not work as explained in the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove hard-coded frame, so allow image to fill all available area dynamically

```
    Image("background")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFill()
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

//        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width,                    // << this !!
//               height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height, alignment: .top)
```